# MongoDb protect database file from anonymous access

Tags: mongodb

I created a mongodb database with this description

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication-without-bypass/

1. created database
2. created admin-user
3. run mongodb with --auth parameter

that works fine.

but how can I really protect the database files from anonymous access?

When someone would take my database-file and run mongodb without `--auth` parameter he would have access to the whole database.

Is there a way to protect the database file itself so I can't just run mongodb without `--auth`?

Best regards

Tobias

Comment: If you have such sensitive data that the usual means of preventing physical access to your data files (access control to the data center, four eyes principle) and host based access (hardening, brute force prevention, MAC and HIDS/NIDS) aren't enough, you should *really* think about an in house solution.

Comment: my project I'm developing is planned to be used from private person who will install this program on there home-pc. there will be no server. so I think its not a big problem. if someone really has access to there pc they may have bigger problems that this one ;)

Comment: Then standard precautions should be enough. Disk encryption if absolutely necessary. On OSX, you could use an encrypted sparse bundle and point `dbpath` to it, as a poor man's solution, if you don't want to encrypt the whole user's directory. Solutions for Linux and Windows were already mentioned.

Comment: my project is written in c# so the primary system is windows. If the enduser really wants protection he/she may create a Bitlocker-drive and run everything in there. Will this also reduce the performace? did you try this already?

Comment: Running MongoDB on Windows is a Very Bad Idea™ performance wise. NTFS and ReFS aren't exactly good performing file systems. Even more so when they are encrypted. But with a single client, you shouldn't notice much of a difference. This however, is not from first hand experience, since I don't use Windows personally. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encrypting data files is only part of an overall security strategy - if someone has access to copy any files from your computer or a backup, they may also be able to snag your encryption keys from the same source. The MongoDB manual has a [Security section](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/security/) which covers general best practices including access control, network exposure, auditing, and a high level checklist.

If you want to encrypt your MongoDB data files you will need to look into a solution for "encryption at rest".

As at MongoDB 2.6, there is no built-in support for data encryption but there are a number of open source as well as commercial solutions available.

The broad categories of encryption at rest are application level or storage encryption (which can be used independently or together, depending on your requirements). Encryption will add some performance overhead for disk I/O, so you should consider this in your testing & evaluation of a suitable solution for your requirements.

A few examples of encryption at rest solutions are:

- [LUKS (Linux Unified Key Setup)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup)
- [Windows Bitlocker Drive Encryption](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831713.aspx)

For more information on supported options, have a read of the [Encryption at Rest](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/security-introduction/#encryption-at-rest) section of the MongoDB security documentation.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer! I will read the section and will also have a look at the encryption-links.

Comment: ok, but if I have a whole collection to protect (f.e. contracts or something like this) there is no really good way to protect the database from unauthorized access right? so the best way is to take care that nobody has access to the database-file and to mongod.exe. I'm using this just for a still small private project but it would be nice to have a passwort-protected file like keepass.